# How do I mount an f2fs partitioned SD card on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sd-card

Similar to [this question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/trying-to-mount-usb-card-reader-to-wsl/78b71482-097c-461e-9550-2ce0f5a973f7), I tried mounting my SD card using wsl. First I installed wsl:

```
wsl --install
```

This installed ubuntu, and after a restart I ran wsl and executed the following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install f2fs-tools
```

Closed wsl and ran this command on powershell with administrator privileges:

```
get-ciminstance -query "select * from win32_diskdrive"
```

Giving me the output:

```
DeviceID           Caption        Partitions Size         Model
--------           -------        ---------- ----         -----
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 SDXC Card      1          255863784960 SDXC Card
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0 SanDisk DA4032 3          31264289280  SanDisk DA4032
```

I then executed the command:

```
wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
```

which returned:

```
The system cannot find the drive specified.
Error code: Wsl/Service/AttachDisk/0x8007000f
```

During which, the SD card mounted in windows file explorer disappeared.

I'm using wsl2

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Stopped         2
```

---

Switched to [Windows 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk#prerequisites) (Version 10.0.22621.1413), as suggested by [harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc), and [Daniel B](https://superuser.com/users/219095/daniel-b)

I ran `get-ciminstance -query "select * from win32_diskdrive"` in powershell with administrative permissions.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C:\Windows\system32> get-ciminstance -query "select * from win32_diskdrive"

DeviceID           Caption        Partitions Size         Model
--------           -------        ---------- ----         -----
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 SDXC Card      1          255863784960 SDXC Card
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0 SanDisk DA4032 3          31264289280  SanDisk DA4032
```

First, installing from the command line, using similar install procedure. Installed Ubuntu. Rebooted and ran cmd with administrative permission:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1413]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
The system cannot find the drive specified.
Error code: Wsl/Service/AttachDisk/0x8007000f

C:\Windows\System32>wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Stopped         2
```

Uninstalled WSL, installed the Windows store WSL and Ubuntu. Rebooted, ran cmd with administrative permission.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1413]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
The system cannot find the drive specified.
Error code: Wsl/Service/AttachDisk/0x8007000f

C:\Windows\System32>wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Stopped         2
```

---

As pointed out in this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/trying-to-mount-usb-card-reader-to-wsl/78b71482-097c-461e-9550-2ce0f5a973f7). WSL is bugged and fails to mount, at least in this specific case of SD card readers.

> Trying to mount USB card reader to WSL. I have Windows 11 running Kali
> using WSL. I have a USB sd card reader that I would like to mount so I
> can view linux file system sdcards. I use: get-ciminstance -query
> "select * from win32_diskdrive", to list my available drives. Then
> use: wsl --mount \.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 --bare, to mount. I received this
> error:
>
> The system cannot find the drive specified.
>
> Error code: Wsl/Service/AttachDisk/0x8007000f
>
> When I put the USB stick into the pc, it shows in file explorer. When
> I run the mount command, it disappears. Any help getting this to work
> would be appreciated.

> This is an old bug. It is well known, but never fixed.
>
> They keep trying to push you away from Windows. Only solution is a
> real solution like VMWare etc. or running native Linux

I've cut my losses and repartitioned my SD card to a Linux and Windows compatible filesystem.

Comment: Try `wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 -bare`.

Comment: `PS C:\Windows\system32> wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 -bare`
`The parameter is incorrect.`
`Error code: Wsl/E_INVALIDARG`
`PS C:\Windows\system32> wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 --bare`
`The system cannot find the drive specified.`
`Error code: Wsl/Service/AttachDisk/0x8007000f`

Comment: may be coincidence, but after I ran `get-ciminstance -query "select * from win32_diskdrive"` WSL would no longer start at all (though, that only happened once)

Comment: WSL still works for me after `get-ciminstance -query "select * from win32_diskdrive"`.

Comment: I found the article [Mount a Linux disk in WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk), which has this text : "Prerequisites : You will need to be on Windows 11 Build 22000 or later, or be running the Microsoft Store version of WSL". Try the Microsoft Store version of Ubuntu (uninstall first the other).

Comment: You are running Windows 10. Linked question is about Windows 11. Are you running the Windows store version of WSL 2? The [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk#prerequisites) are pretty clear.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I will install Windows 11. As for harrmc's question, searching Ubuntu in the Windows store shows that "This product is installed".

Comment: Are you sure to have installed WSL version 2? Check using `wsl --list --verbose`.

Comment: I am confident. `wsl -l -v` was executed in the original post. Currently testing on Windows 11.